# Fundamental groups of resolutions of complete intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X^k$ be a complete intersection in $\mathbb CP^n$ of dimension $k>1$. Is it true that a smooth variety obtained by resolutions 
of singularities of $X$ is simply-connected?

Note that in the case $X^k$ is smooth itself,  $\pi_1(X^k)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, take $X$ to be the projective cone in $\mathbb P^3$ of a smooth plane curve $C$ of degree at least $3$. Then blowing up the vertex gives a resolution that is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle over $C$, and the fundamental group is that of $C$.

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you think there can be any positive statement in this direction?
